# SSRS Lock rectangle in Top of report when scrolling

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, business-intelligence

I know there is a solution to keep a tablix header in top of report when scrolling, but do you how how to do this with a rectangle which is outside of tablix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You can either use the tablix header (which you're aware of) or the page header.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have tried creating a table and placing the rectangle in the table??